# How to freeze the header row in an Excel spreadsheet exported from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, gridview, export

I'm exporting an ASP.NET gridview to Excel using the following function.  The formatting is working really well, except I need to freeze the header row in Excel on the export. I'm really trying to avoid using a 3rd party Excel plugin for this, but unless there's some archaic excel markup in my AddExcelStyling function.

```
    Public Sub exportGrid(ByVal psFileName As String)

        Response.Clear()
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=PriceSheet.xls")
        Response.Charset = ""
        Me.EnableViewState = False
        Dim sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim htw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
        sfggcPriceSheet.RenderControl(htw)
        Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=""text/html; charset=utf-8"">" + Environment.NewLine)
        Response.Write(AddExcelStyling())
        Response.Write(sw.ToString())
        Response.Write("</body>")
        Response.Write("</html>")
        Response.End()

    End Sub
```

And the formatting black magic:

```
   Private Function AddExcelStyling() As String


    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'" + Environment.NewLine + _
    "xmlns:x='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel'" + Environment.NewLine + _
    "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>" + Environment.NewLine + _
    "<head>")
    sb.Append("<style>" + Environment.NewLine)

    sb.Append("@page")
    sb.Append("{margin:.25in .25in .25in .25in;" + Environment.NewLine)

    sb.Append("mso-header-margin:.025in;" + Environment.NewLine)
    sb.Append("mso-footer-margin:.025in;" + Environment.NewLine)

    sb.Append("mso-page-orientation:landscape;}" + Environment.NewLine)
    sb.Append("</style>" + Environment.NewLine)

    sb.Append("<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>" + Environment.NewLine)
    sb.Append("<x:ExcelWorkbook>" + Environment.NewLine)

    sb.Append("<x:ExcelWorksheets>" + Environment.NewLine)
    sb.Append("<x:ExcelWorksheet>" + Environment.NewLine)

    sb.Append("<x:Name>PriceSheets</x:Name>" + Environment.NewLine)
    sb.Append("<x:WorksheetOptions>" + Environment.NewLine)

    sb.Append("<x:Print>" + Environment.NewLine)
    sb.Append("<x:ValidPrinterInfo/>" + Environment.NewLine)

    sb.Append("<x:PaperSizeIndex>9</x:PaperSizeIndex>" + Environment.NewLine)
    sb.Append("<x:HorizontalResolution>600</x:HorizontalResolution" + Environment.NewLine)

    sb.Append("<x:VerticalResolution>600</x:VerticalResolution" + Environment.NewLine)
    sb.Append("</x:Print>" + Environment.NewLine)

    sb.Append("<x:Selected/>" + Environment.NewLine)
    sb.Append("<x:DoNotDisplayGridlines/>" + Environment.NewLine)

    sb.Append("<x:ProtectContents>False</x:ProtectContents>" + Environment.NewLine)
    sb.Append("<x:ProtectObjects>False</x:ProtectObjects>" + Environment.NewLine)

    sb.Append("<x:ProtectScenarios>False</x:ProtectScenarios>" + Environment.NewLine)
    sb.Append("</x:WorksheetOptions>" + Environment.NewLine)

    sb.Append("</x:ExcelWorksheet>" + Environment.NewLine)
    sb.Append("</x:ExcelWorksheets>" + Environment.NewLine)

    sb.Append("<x:WindowHeight>12780</x:WindowHeight>" + Environment.NewLine)
    sb.Append("<x:WindowWidth>19035</x:WindowWidth>" + Environment.NewLine)

    sb.Append("<x:WindowTopX>0</x:WindowTopX>" + Environment.NewLine)
    sb.Append("<x:WindowTopY>15</x:WindowTopY>" + Environment.NewLine)

    sb.Append("<x:ProtectStructure>False</x:ProtectStructure>" + Environment.NewLine)
    sb.Append("<x:ProtectWindows>False</x:ProtectWindows>" + Environment.NewLine)

    sb.Append("</x:ExcelWorkbook>" + Environment.NewLine)
    sb.Append("</xml><![endif]-->" + Environment.NewLine)

    sb.Append("</head>" + Environment.NewLine)
    sb.Append("<body>" + Environment.NewLine)

    Return sb.ToString()

End Function
```

Comment: What do you mean by freeze the header row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the WorksheetOption element to something like the following:

```
<x:WorksheetOptions>
     <x:Selected/>
     <x:FreezePanes/>
     <x:FrozenNoSplit/>
     <x:SplitHorizontal>1</x:SplitHorizontal>
     <x:TopRowBottomPane>1</x:TopRowBottomPane>
     <x:ActivePane>2</x:ActivePane>
     <x:Panes>
      <x:Pane>
       <x:Number>3</x:Number>
      </x:Pane>
      <x:Pane>
       <x:Number>2</x:Number>
      </x:Pane>
     </x:Panes>
     <x:ProtectContents>False</x:ProtectContents>
     <x:ProtectObjects>False</x:ProtectObjects>
     <x:ProtectScenarios>False</x:ProtectScenarios>
    </x:WorksheetOptions>
```

Notice the FreezePanes element. I cut this out of a spreadsheet that I had saved as HTML with the first row frozen. When this file is opened with Excel, the first row is frozen.

**EDIT:**
To have the header row print on each page, you will need something like this:

```
<x:ExcelName>
  <x:Name>Print_Area</x:Name>
  <x:SheetIndex>1</x:SheetIndex>
  <x:Formula>=Sheet1!$A$2:$F$97</x:Formula>
 </x:ExcelName>
 <x:ExcelName>
  <x:Name>Print_Titles</x:Name>
  <x:SheetIndex>1</x:SheetIndex>
  <x:Formula>=Sheet1!$1:$1</x:Formula>
 </x:ExcelName>
```

You will need to modify the values in the formula dynamically for your data.

Comment: Awesome!  That's exactly what I was looking for.  
Any idea how to get it to print that row on each page?  I've tried your trick of saving as HTML then looking at it, but I'm doing something wrong and don't get any of the excel options when I do that.

Comment: Hmmm, looks like I have to save it as XML spreadsheet to get those tags.  The rows to repeat for printing option appears to used named ranges rather than options in the <x:Print> elements.  I might be stuck.

Comment: I added a bit to my answer to address the issue of printing the header row on each page. You will need to set the print_area dynamically. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a trick that I employ when I am trying to do "specialty" formatting, etc...

Create an XLS with all the row and cell formats you'd like already expressed. Then COPY it, add your data, and SAVE it.

In this manner you do not need any payed-for plug-ins, and you ALWAYS get EXACTLY whatever formatting you want...

Need more than one specialty? Create another my_MT_Excel.xls with the needed formatting.

You could have a folder full of these things all ready to go without resorting to the more intricate programming techniques.

tob