# Export to Excel and Freeze Top Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

As a coder, I figure my job is to produce tools and procedures that make everyone's job easier.  I have an ASP.Net GridView that is pretty huge (20 pages +) and that is pretty cumbersome for the accounting staff to have to flip through.  So I've coded up an Export to Excel button, and it is working as desired.  But now, they have a really long xls and it is difficult to remember what column is tied to what data.  So, I've been looking for a means of exporting that same xls with FreezePanes enabled so it will open up with the first row frozen.  I'm not finding an example of how this is done.

Here's what I have at the moment, and it works beautifully, so I don't want to change the approach.  I just want to get this code to freeze row 1.

```
protected void ExportGridviewToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myMonth = MonthTextBox.Text;
    string myYear = YearTextBox.Text;
    SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["InterfaceDev"].ConnectionString);
    string myCommandText = "GatherZeroBillingExtensions";
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myCommandText, myConn);
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", myMonth);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", myYear);
    SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
    DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];
    ZeroBillExtGridView.AllowPaging = false;
    ZeroBillExtGridView.DataSource = myDataTable;
    ZeroBillExtGridView.DataBind();

    string myDesktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    string myFilename = "ZeroBillingExtensions_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".xls";
    string myFullyQualifiedPath = myDesktopPath + "\\" + myFilename;
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", myFullyQualifiedPath));
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    StringWriter myStringWriter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter myHtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(myStringWriter);
    //Change the Header Row back to white color
    ZeroBillExtGridView.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
    //Applying stlye to gridview header cells
    for (int i = 0; i < ZeroBillExtGridView.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        ZeroBillExtGridView.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-color", "#507CD1");
    }
    int j = 1;
    //Set alternate row color
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in ZeroBillExtGridView.Rows)
    {
        gvrow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        if (j <= ZeroBillExtGridView.Rows.Count)
        {
            if (j % 2 != 0)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < gvrow.Cells.Count; k++)
                {
                    gvrow.Cells[k].Style.Add("background-color", "#EFF3FB");
                }
            }
        }
        j++;
    }
    ZeroBillExtGridView.RenderControl(myHtmlTextWriter);
    Response.Write(myStringWriter.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: You're exporting the GridView as HTML. That's a bad idea. Instead, use a library such as [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), which specifically supports freeze panes.

Comment: Well, we live and learn.  I'm not familiar with EPPlus, but just a few minutes on the site makes it clear that it is exactly what I need.  Thanks mason!!

Comment: Mason, I had to post back one more time to say a huge "Thank you" for pointing me to EPPlus.  What a great library of tools.  I've already recommended it to a developer friend.  EPPlus is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

You can't cause the panes to freeze as you are not actually creating an Excel document. You are creating an HTML document with a .xls extension. HTML has no notion of "freezing" panes or rows. If you want to use Excel features, you need to generate a real Excel document by either using OpenXML, XML, Office Interop (on the server), or third-party tools.

See example of formatting with [XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335166/how-to-freeze-the-header-row-in-an-excel-spreadsheet-exported-from-asp-net)

```
<WorksheetOptions
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">

<Selected/>
<FreezePanes/>
<FrozenNoSplit/>

<!--- Bottom row number of top pane. --->
<SplitHorizontal>1</SplitHorizontal>

<!---
    Offset row of bottom frame. This is not the actual row
    number of the overall Excel document, but rather the
    index of the available rows for this pane. This number
    cannot exclude rows, it can merely set the offset
    scroll of this pane. (1) scrolls to the top of the
    frame (first row).
--->
<TopRowBottomPane>1</TopRowBottomPane>

</WorksheetOptions>
```